# How to integrate direct + social login into rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth, rails-api

I want to integrate direct + social login into a rails API preferably [devise](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise) + [omniauth](https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth) and once the user is authenticated then the API should return some token say JWT and I assume omniauth-twitter and omniauth-facebook supports only from Rails UI (social login button), Is there any way I can use it from a rails API, I came across this [example](https://github.com/muZk/rails5-api-jwt-facebook-auth) in which the facebook user can be authenticated using access-token but I want this to implemented using `FACEBOOK_KEY` and `FACEBOOK_SECRET`

How to integrate direct + social login using rails API?

Comment: checkout dookeeper/devise tutorials. They pair together alot